# How to render the HTML of a django CMS plugin by id from Python

Tags: python, django-cms

My use case is the need to render a pdf out of the given plugin, although that function might also be used for eg search index composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the django CMS codebase there's `cms.templatetags.render_alias_plugin` which code isn't straightforward, but when stripped out it can look as following:

```py
def render_plugin(plugin: CMSPlugin, request: HttpRequest) -> str:
    plugins = plugin.get_descendants().order_by('placeholder', 'path')
    plugins = [plugin] + list(plugins)
    plugins = downcast_plugins(plugins, request=request)
    plugins = list(plugins)
    plugins[0].parent_id = None
    plugins = build_plugin_tree(plugins)
    renderer = get_toolbar_from_request(request).content_renderer
    html: str = renderer.render_plugin(
        instance=plugins[0],
        context={'request': request},
        editable=False,
    )
    return mark_safe(html)


cms_plugin = CMSPlugin.objects.get(id=cms_plugin_id)
render_plugin(cms_plugin, request)
```

If needed the http request can also be faked, an example of that can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/victor.yunenko/djangocms-algolia/-/blob/a03d65e68c25aa6224074ec117d3bb02a93ceeaa/djangocms_algolia/index.py#L21).